# Pass POST data in form with no action url Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have here a form with two buttons in it and when submitting, it doesn't pass the data on another page.

```
<form method="post" id="form-id">

   #some form inputs here...
                   
   <a class="btn btn-success" id="yourFunction()" href="{% #url_here %}">published</a>
   <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% #url_here %}">save as draft</a>
</form>
```

Does anyone know how to pass a post data in  tag in Django, if the form tag has no action URL?

thanks in advance!

Comment: `The <input type="submit"> defines a button for submitting the form data to a form-handler.`

Comment: You can also create a Js function that can be called according to which button is clicked and pass the `href` to the Js function and replace the `action` of the form. This just an idea how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a multiple button inside a form where this button has a different location/URL to go you can use this Javascript property to modify or set the action to the different buttons inside the form.

```
function yourFunction() {
    document.getElementById("form-id").action = "your url";
}
```